# Google Analytics cookies _ga and _gid still appearing in Chrome after installing a GDPR consent plugin in WordPress

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, cookie, eu-cookie-law, gdpr

Trying to get my Wordpress blog into GDPR compliance.

I've got most of my cookies under control with a consent plugin (Cookie Notice) but I'm concerned about Google Analytics cookies _ga and _gid, which I see in the cookie for my site's URL on Chrome, despite my best efforts to suppress them. (I use Chrome developer tools to view them.)

However, it appears that I do not get the _ga or _gid cookies when I view the cookies on the same page in either MS Edge or Firefox. That makes me think it's a Chrome thing (which would make sense, since Chrome is Google's browser?)

Am I off-base?